# How to solve Flutter VS Code suggestion Error

Tags: flutter, dart

This just happened on my specific flutter project, All the suggestion is broken except the active hovered suggestion.

How to solve it? how could it happened?

[image: error code suggestion]

Comment: Have you tried restarting VSCode and your pc? Maybe look for updates for VSCode and the flutter plugin. Maybe running `flutter clean`. You should add to your question what you've tried so far to solve it.

Comment: Thanks! i've tried flutter clean & pub get, restarting pc, open vs code again. it solved the problem. You may answer it and i will upvote and add it as the answer

Comment: I added it as an answer. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried restarting VSCode and your pc? Maybe look for updates for VSCode and the flutter plugin. Maybe running `flutter clean`.